# serial port giving the junk characters when connected to raspberry pi board

Tags: linux

i have connected the PC to pi board with serial cable, and i am using the mini-com to communicate, i have tried all  baud rate. But i am getting the unreadable character on mini-com. i am trying to make the board boot using u-boot, so i need the serial communication. How can i use the mini-com and what should i change to get the proper out put on mini-com.
and i also tried with this link procedure http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/raspberry-pi-serial-port. still i am getting the same junk output.
 please somebody help me to resolve this.

Comment: maybe minicom is still configured to send some characters at start, used to communicate with modems.
Try `$ minicom -s` and then delete all characters in modem configuration (if there are characters)

Comment: There are more parameters except the baudrate. check the stopbits, parity,etc.